# Clustering points by number and accumulation

Tags: qgis, point, clustering, numbering, accumulated

I'm recently working on a project, where I have a dataset of 450 Points. I need to cluster them into groups of maximum 80 and minimum 60 Points, which should also be located next to each other.

By using the K-Means, I get groups with a far bigger number of points. When I want to split them, using the field calculator, the clustering gets mixed up, because the fids don't match the clustering and coordinates. Do you have any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is not one exact way to solve this problem. I propose an iterative approach:

1. Use `overlay_nearest()` function with a limit of say 70 points, then calculate the distance to all these points and get the largest of these distances = for each point the radius of a buffer that encloses exactly 70 points. Create a new attribute field named `max` with this value (see expression below).
2. Identify the point with the smallest `max` value: this is the first cluster.
3. Exclude the points within this first cluster, then repeat steps 1 to 3 until no more points are left.

The expression to use in step 1:

```
array_max(
    array_foreach(
        overlay_nearest (
            @layer,
            $geometry,
            limit:=70
        ),  
        distance (
            $geometry,
            @element
        )
    )
)
```

Result after the first five iterations:

[image]